How to Repair Aluminum Siding J Channel Outside Corner
What are possible ways to repair this mangled j channel corner? It's a single piece of aluminum that runs to the roof, so it would be a pain to remove all the siding to replace it.


There probably is space to slip stiff wood/metal/plastic inside of that corner to push out the dents.  There are also dent pullers found in auto part stores that might work.  I would place the stiffness of the corner has being a bit stiffer than newer aluminum foil pie plates and much softer than the older real aluminum pie plates/pans.

Alternately, since it appears to be solely an aesthetic issue, you could simply get a new piece of corner and glue it over the bashed up section.
